# Nested Loops and end value

Tags: java, loops, nested

the last value for c1 before it gets out of the loop (and thereafter) is 6. How is it 6? The last known value for that variable is 5.

here is the code snipplet

```
int c1, c2;

for (c2 = 4; c2 <= 5; c2++)
{
for (c1 = 2; c1 <= 5; c1++)
{
System.out.println("#"+""+c1); 
}
System.out.println(c2 + "  " + c1); 
}
System.out.println("\nLoop is done");
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the information from your comment; and please indent you code.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with *nested* for loops: you could take off the outer for loop and remove the `c2` variable, and you'd still see exactly the same thing happening to `c1`.

Answer (score 5):

No the last value is 6. After iterating 5 times it does `c1++` and then the next iteration of the loop it fails the for loop's `c1 <= 5` check and exits the loop. But c1 is  already 6 then. But that is never printed because that is in the loop only.

Comment: let me understand you. The order of execution for java is as follow:
1. it evaluates c1 =1
2. it evaluates that 1 is less than the Boolean condition
3. executes the body
4. THEN it does the c1=c1 + 1 (which is the increment). 

... in the last iteration, 
1. it prints the body (which is 5)
2. do the increment which is 5 + 1
3. check that the Boolean statement is false because 6<5
4. retains the last known c1 value stored in that variable which is 6

Comment: Yes, that's how for loops generally work in most languages. Three statements, in this case separated by `;`, first is executed before the entire loops starts (init, only once), one loop condition tested before each loop (loop again or not), and then the last statement executed after each loop.

Comment: I understand now. Guess it's just one of those things where ( although logically and sequentially makes sense), still have to remember. Nuance some sort

Answer (score 0):

The for loop checks the condition to determine whether it should skip the body.  Your condition is `c1 <= 5`.  Thus, on the last iteration, `c1 = 5,` and then it does `c1++`.  So c1=6, at which point `c1 <= 5` is false.

Comment: is this just something java automatically does to get out of the loop? I understand that the last iteration c1 = 5, but why do the additional C1++? 

Let me understand you. So as part of the header, when it gets to c1=5, it still goes through the header and increment the 1. After that, it notices the Boolean is false and exists the loop, but it retains the value of the final statement c1 = c1 + 1?

Comment: At the end of each iteration, the for loop executes the increment statement, `c1++`.  Then, it jumps back to the beginning of the loop.  At that point, it evaluates the condition `c1 <= 5`.  The last iteration caused `c1++ = 6`.  So, in evaluating the condition, it decides it is false, then breaks out of the loop instead of executing the body.

Comment: Kevin-
It looks my we're on the same page. So is it just a nuance that the last value is 6? If I did not have the print statement outside of the loop, it would be hard to know the last value is an additional increment. If the print statement is inside the loop, the value would be 5.

Comment: That is correct.  Most languages with for loops have the same behavior--if you try accessing the counter variable after such a loop, its value will be something that fails to meet the test condition.

Answer (score 0):

For loop consits of three (optional) parts: initialization, termination condition and update statement.
The update statement (c1++) is always executed at the end of each iteration in a loop.

In final iteration for c1 = 5 condition is true since 5 <=5. Println will be executed and after that the update statement which will increment c1 to 6. Since 6 is not <=5, loop will terminate.

So the final known value is indeed 6 and not 5, note that otherwise loop would never stop since condition would be true.